# To what class does the code in .cshtml file belong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to know what class the code in .cshtml file belong to such that I can trace the higher hierarchy. So my question is

> To what class does the code in .cshtml file belong?

Comment: Files do not belong to classes.  If you're actually asking what class they inherit from, it depends how you're compiling them.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/dissecting-razor-part-1-pieces-of.html

Comment: I think this book is useful: Programming Microsoft
ASP.NET MVC, Third
Edition

Answer (score 1):

.cshtml extension if for a MVC view using razor view engine. So if you want to know what's the Model class for your view, look for the @model directive which should be at the top of the file. ie:

> @model MyNamespace.MyModel

Now if what you want to know what class a View inherits from in the .Net framework. I think the closest thing to it will be the System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult class. But keep in mind that in MVC View engine there is not a direct relationship between the View code and the ViewResult. Kind of like the relathionship between .aspx files and the code behind class. Here is a good start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpage(v=vs.111).aspx

I hope this helps with your question.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly then the .cshtml file doesn't 'belong' to a class. The Razor View Engine parses the contents of the view passed to it via the controller's `return View()` method.

As the parser engine has semantic knowledge of C# (and VB for that matter) it is able to distinguish between the text and C# code blocks and handle them appropriately.

If you're after a greater understanding of how the view engine works then I might recommend taking a look at building your own simple view engine, doing such a task is a great way to understand the inner workings of how the view engine works.